# Gmail auto Canned Response sends to wrong address

Tags: gmail-filters, automation, gmail-canned-response

I have a small irritating problem which is that I'm often being confused with some other guy with the exact same name who lives on the other side of Sweden. Which means that I receive quite a lot of emails that are intended for the other guy. To address this problem (without having to manually send a response to everyone who accidentally sends me an email) I've set up a Canned Response in Gmail, with a rule identifying certain key words, to be sent to the original sender.

Here's where my problem is though. The Canned Response is created, the rule/filter is active even the automatic response is triggered. However it sends the response with a faulty envelope/to-address.

Apparently this setup for some reason triggers the BATV (Bounce Address Tag Validation) to alter the to-address to get a Simple Private Signature (prvs-tag). Meaning that an original **name.name@mail.com** address after the BATV becomes    **prvs=40800f526=name.name@mail.com**. And this means that the original sender never receives the reply.

Does anyone know why this happens, and if there's some way to get around it?